# Docker - how to prevent a file being override when using volume?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js, docker-compose

First of all, I have a dockerized application, which is consisted of 3 containers (web, backend, database).

folder structure

```
- backend
   ...
   - package.json
   - Dockerfile
- web
   ...
   - package.json
   - Dockerfile

- docker-compose.yml
```

This is `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./web:/app
      - /app/.next
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ...
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    container_name: mongodb
    ...
```

web/Dockerfile - which is copied from [nextJS official examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile)

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**Problem**
After running `docker-compose up -d`, an error occurs in the `web` container.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Then I realized that the volume in `web` override the `server.js`

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./web:/app // The error is because of this line
      ...
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

All right, so after I remove

```
volumes:
      - ./web:/app
```

, `web` container works fine now, but live reloading doesn't work now.
I have to re-build my docker image to see the changes after I modify the code.

So now my question is, is it possible to keep `server.js` in my docker container, while still having the live reloading functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Instead of mounting the entire `./web` directory, you can mount a specific directory for your source code. This ensures `server.js` remains within the container while allowing live updates.

But, importantly, don't mount the `.next` folder or the `node_modules` folder. This approach maintains your built files and installed modules inside the container while allowing source code changes to be mirrored inside the container, enabling live reloading.

Here is the modified `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./web/pages:/app/pages
      - ./web/components:/app/components
      - ./web/styles:/app/styles
      - ./web/public:/app/public
      # Add other directories as needed, but do NOT add the .next directory or node_modules.
    depends_on:
      - backend
```